Meaning of the word "strike"
What does "strike" mean in this sentence? Here's a football (soccer) commentary between West Ham and Liverpool.

Half Time Down at the break Ref Anthony Taylor blows his whistle, and
that's it for the first half.
There was plenty of promise during the early stages, and Mohammed
Kudus has hit the post, but Liverpool have been well on top since
scoring two relatively soft goals.
After Luis Díaz and Cody Gakpo strikes, Mohamed Salah made it 3-0
to put the Reds firmly in the driving seat here


What do you suppose it to mean?  Read the context! What two significant events (one for Diaz and one for Gakpo) happened in the match before "Mohamed Salah made it 3-0".  It should be pretty easy to guess this, if you know about football.

I have no idea because "strike" has lots of meanings. The word can mean to hit the ball hard. Is it correct here?

Would "hit the ball hard" be significant events in the context of a game of football? Look again and think a little bit.  What two events happened before the third goal?

I can't guess. What does it mean?

The syntax is a little odd; instead of the normal "After strikes by Diaz and Gakpo" or "After the Diaz and Gakpo strikes" we have "After Diaz and Gakpo strikes".

Commentary is spoken, not written.
After Luis Díaz and Cody Gakpo strikes=
After strikes by Luis Díaz and Cody Gakpo=goals scored by those two players.
The names of the players are used as attributive nouns.
Striker:
A player on a team whose job is to attack with the ball and score goals.They stay near the opponent's penalty area in the best position to try and shoot when they receive the ball.
striker
So, in this case in that sentence, it means to score a goal.

Thanks a lot. If it means to score. What's the difference between to "strike" and to "score?"

downvoter: The upvoted answer doesn't even have a reference or explain how strike can mean goal.

@dwiardianto, "strike" is a word a commentator would use.  "Score" is a word an ordinary person would use.
